# Cannot exit Android Kiosk mode on Android 6.x

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, kiosk

I have an application where Kiosk mode is implemented. However, on Android 6.x, I cannot exit Kiosk mode by pressing the Back button and the Multi-screen button.

I am thinking about to implement a button in the app where user can exit Kiosk mode on Android. Ideally, the Pin screen should be prompted and allows user to enter the device password.

I found around but seems like I could not see any solution for it. My question is that, is it even possible to exit the Kiosk mode from an app by pressing the button.

Any documentation would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You should go through following Google Codelabs guide:
[Build Applications for Single-Use Devices](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#0)

There is proper introduction to make Kiosk App and how to exit from it.

Android Marshmallow bring hefty amount features that make kiosk app implementing quite easy without needing hacking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. While a link to a helpful external resource is always welcome, please also *quote a key excerpt from the page you're linking to*. This is so that if the website goes down or the page is (re)moved, then this answer won't become useless.

Answer (score 0):

If any app is designed and developed for kiosk mode, as per ideal implementation where are cases are considered while development, it should not exit from kiosk mode. the better way to implement it is to provide a way through to disable the kiosk mode from within the app itself.So that time and when required user can disable kiosk mode and can gracefully exit from app.

http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/